# QFileDialog not showing Fonts folder

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to Browse the Fonts folder in c:\Windows and get the filepath of the selected font.

But when the Dialog Box opens it does not show the Font folder in Windows.

```
Void SumFont::FontChange()
{
    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"),
        "/home",
        tr("Fonts (*.ttf)"));

    QlineEditSetFont->setText(filePath);
    isChanged = true;
    stdstrLocation = filePath.toStdString();
    this->isChanged = true; 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the path? If Qt cannot access it, the dialog shows a default folder.

Comment: @ymoreau yes dialog shows the defaut folder.

Comment: You want "c:\Windows" but "/home" in your code

Comment: @Deep  i can browse to C:\Windows but i don't see Font folder.

Comment: when i try something like this QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"),
  "/home",
  tr("Fonts (*.*)"));

Comment: I am able to see Font folder but when i try to access it i get message that font folder is not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows the fonts folder, apart from being system protected in other ways, has a special font display mode set in `desktop.ini` by this line: `CLSID={BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}`. That makes the `AppID {50d69d24-961d-4828-9d1c-5f4717f226d1}` being responsible for displaying this folder in all the system browsers. Unfortunately, the Windows-native file dialog in Qt can't display the font folder as a proper font viewer (for reasons unknown to me). There are two ways to work around this problem I'm aware of though.

First is messing with Windows itself - just rename the `desktop.ini` file in the fonts folder to something like `desktop.ini.bak`. You'll need administrator privileges for that, so do it from `cmd` or PowerShell started "as administrator". Also UAC must probably be turned off. After that the fonts folder will become a regular folder, and `QFileDialog` will be able to display it as any other folder. This is really not recommended in production, but I don't know why you need to access the fonts folder directly anyway.

Second method is not using the Windows-native file dialog.

```
QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"),
        QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::FontsLocation)[0],
        tr("Fonts (*.ttf);;Everything (*.*)"), nullptr,
        QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```

The code above will open the Qt fallback dialog, which doesn’t care about `desktop.ini`.

Anyway, be careful when directly accessing the fonts folder. Especially if you plan to put files in it. Windows may have some hooks for updating the font cache that may not work correctly this way.